Failed to deploy "web app" with "docker compose". No logs, no explanation
I was able to succesfully start a web app according this tutorial Create a docker compose app (first part, no database).
I then tried to do the same with my toy application. This is a java application that uses api telegram: it just "echoes" messages send to it from Telegram and stores them in a db. I used an azure "webapp" because it is the only possibility deployable with a docker compose file
Here is my docker compose (docker-compose-az.yml):
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:oraclelinux9
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: echo
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./mysql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

  app:
    image: app
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: DockerfileAZ
    depends_on:
      - db

volumes:
  db_data:


here is my dockerfile (dockerfileAZ)

FROM --platform=linux/amd64 eclipse-temurin:17-jdk

RUN mkdir -p /opt/app/lib

COPY ServerToyProject.jar /opt/app/
COPY lib/* /opt/app/lib/

RUN echo "done: target/lib/* /opt/app/lib/"

WORKDIR /opt/app

CMD ["java", "-cp", "ServerToyProject.jar:lib/*:.", "main.Echo"]

RUN echo "done: java executed"

here is my azure command
az webapp create --resource-group resource-group-echo --plan app-service-plan-echo --name tmp2 --multicontainer-config-type compose --multicontainer-config-file docker-compose-az.yml

(resource group and app service plan do exist)
Problem are:

I don't see logs in the logs tab of deploy center.
The app does not work


Consider that locally it works fine. By "locally" I mean that I start it using the docker compose, without using azure.

Sometimes(!!) I see the logs in the tab of deploy center. There was apparently a problem with the volume paths.

Could it be a configuration problem: what to put in Registry source and server URL?



After some thoughts and after the answer of I came up with a slightly different approach.
I pushed to images on an azure registry. Those images are created by those two dockerfiles:
Dockerfile.mysql
FROM mysql:oraclelinux9
COPY ./mysql/*.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE=echo
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password

DockerfileAZ
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jdk

RUN mkdir -p /opt/app/lib

COPY ServerToyProject.jar /opt/app/
COPY lib/* /opt/app/lib/

WORKDIR /opt/app

CMD ["java", "-cp", "ServerToyProject.jar:lib/*:.", "main.Echo"]

docker-compose-az:
services:
  db:
    image: registrytmp.azurecr.io/sqlaz:latest
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: echo
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql

  app:
    image: registrytmp.azurecr.io/fromdockerfileaz:latest
    depends_on:
      - db

volumes:
  db_data:

(basically I am now using an azure registry, and the sql scripts are executed by the docker file , not the docker compose (there was an obvious issue with the location of the mysql directory))
I run the docker-compose-az file in intellij and it worked. In azure web app I failed again. I also wrote a complete gibberish config as experiment and I had NO LOGS at all.


You Should enable logging using the Azure Portal or the Azure CLI - az webapp log config --name tmp2 --resource-group resource-group-echo --application-logging true --level verbose

There is a misconfiguration in the Azure Web App service settings and issues with volume mounting.

When configuring the multi-container web app, you need to specify the Docker registry source and server URL. If you're using Azure Container Registry (ACR).

TelegramLongPollingBot:
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.TelegramLongPollingBot;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.methods.send.SendMessage;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.Update;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.exceptions.TelegramApiException;

@Component
public class EchoBot extends TelegramLongPollingBot {

    @Value("${telegram.bot.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${telegram.bot.token}")
    private String token;

    @Override
    public String getBotUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    @Override
    public String getBotToken() {
        return token;
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
        if (update.hasMessage() && update.getMessage().hasText()) {
            String messageText = update.getMessage().getText();
            Long chatId = update.getMessage().getChatId();

            SendMessage message = new SendMessage();
            message.setChatId(chatId.toString());
            message.setText(messageText);

            try {
                execute(message);
                // Store message in the database
                saveMessage(update.getMessage().getChatId(), update.getMessage().getText());
            } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void saveMessage(Long chatId, String messageText) {
        // Implement your database save logic here
    }
}

Update Docker Compose for ACR:
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: <acr-name>.azurecr.io/mysql:latest
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: echo
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./mysql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

  app:
    image: <acr-name>.azurecr.io/app:latest
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://db:3306/echo
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=root
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=password
    volumes:
      - ./app:/opt/app

volumes:
  db_data:

Output:


Go to the Azure portal, navigate to web app, and check the logs in the Log Stream or Diagnose and solve problems section.

Logs:
Creating network "tmp2_default" with the default driver
Creating volume "tmp2_db_data" with default driver
Pulling db (echoRegistry.azurecr.io/db:latest)...
latest: Pulling from echoRegistry.azurecr.io/db
Digest: sha256:...
Status: Downloaded newer image for echoRegistry.azurecr.io/db:latest
Pulling app (echoRegistry.azurecr.io/app:latest)...
latest: Pulling from echoRegistry.azurecr.io/app
Digest: sha256:...
Status: Downloaded newer image for echoRegistry.azurecr.io/app:latest
Creating tmp2_db_1   ... done
Creating tmp2_app_1  ... done
db_1   | 2024-08-05T10:00:00.000000Z 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
db_1   | Version: '8.0.25'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.

app_1  | 2024-08-05 10:00:01 INFO  [main] - Starting Echo Application...
app_1  | 2024-08-05 10:00:01 INFO  [main] - Connecting to database at db:3306
app_1  | 2024-08-05 10:00:01 INFO  [main] - Database connected successfully.
app_1  | 2024-08-05 10:00:01 INFO  [main] - Echo application started successfully.

app_1  | 2024-08-05 10:00:05 INFO  [main] - Received message: Hello, world!
app_1  | 2024-08-05 10:00:05 INFO  [main] - Echoing message: Hello, world!
app_1  | 2024-08-05 10:00:05 INFO  [main] - Message stored in database.


thanks for the answer. Two questions
have you used an IDE to deploy the application?
I see now a problem with the directory mysql, which is not available in the cloud, but only locally

Locally tested in IDE and deployed through azure CLI. To avoid the MySQL directory issues you should clear that all necessary files are included within the Docker image itself. Copy all the SQL scripts directly into the Docker image.

I have edited the question. Still no logs AT ALL!

Please cross check all the network settings.
